# When i Click on kendo Gird edit Button, # automatically added in URL?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have one kendo grid, grid has one edit button which open bootstrap model dialog box, but when i click on grid edit button, it add # in URL.

How can i remove this?

**kendo Grid Edit Button Code**

```
                {
                    title: "Action",
                    attributes: { "style": "text-align:center;" },
                    headerAttributes:
                    {
                        "style": "text-align:center;white-space: normal;background:rgba(0, 101, 179, 1) !important;color:white;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid white;text-align:center"
                    },
                    command:
                        [
                            {
                                name: "edit", iconClass: "k-icon k-i-pencil", text: "", click: openEditDialogBox
                            }
                        ]
                }
```

I call javascript function on edit button click.

Comment: in openEditDialogBox try return false and/or e.preventDefault()

Comment: It Worked! Thanks